# How to pivot specific columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr

I'm fed up of trying, so brownie points for anyone who helps me. I've got the following data:

```
df <- structure(list(type = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k"), female = c(NA, 3, NA, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1, 16, 43, 
10), prop_total_female = c(NA, 0.04, NA, 0.01, NA, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.01, 0.21, 0.55, 0.13), male = c(2, NA, 2, NA, 1, 8, 1, NA, 
11, 34, 12), prop_total_male = c(0.03, NA, 0.03, NA, 0.01, 0.11, 
0.01, NA, 0.15, 0.48, 0.17)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

type  female   prop_total_female    male    prop_total_male
   a      NA                  NA       2               0.03
   b       3                0.04      NA                 NA   
   c      NA                  NA       2               0.03
   d       1                0.01      NA                 NA   
   e      NA                  NA       1               0.01
   f       2                0.03       8               0.11
   g       2                0.03       1               0.01
   h       1                0.01      NA                 NA   
   i      16                0.21      11               0.15
   j      43                0.55      34               0.48
   k      10                0.13      12               0.17
```

I want to pivot the data to get one column called `gender`, from `male` and `female` respectively, and another column called `prop` from `prop_total_female` and `prop_total_male`. So the desired dataframe will have three columns: `type`, `gender`, and `prop`. A `tidyverse` solution is preferred.

And to @user438383 who will inevitably mark my question as a duplicate, at least give me a solution before resuming your idle life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `names_pattern` and the corresponding `.value` in `names_to` when you have dynamic column names you want to pivot. Because your name pattern is slightly peculiar (it has only one group for the `male`/`female` columns, i.e. there is no `_` and prefix), the pattern will add some NAs that you can remove.

If you wish to keep the NAs that were in the original df, you can use `filter(!is.na(gender))` instead.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-type, names_pattern = "(prop_total)_(.*)", 
               names_to = c(".value", "gender")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(prop_total))

# # A tibble: 16 × 3
#    type  gender prop_total
#    <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
#  1 a     male         0.03
#  2 b     female       0.04
#  3 c     male         0.03
#  4 d     female       0.01
#  5 e     male         0.01
#  6 f     female       0.03
#  7 f     male         0.11
#  8 g     female       0.03
#  9 g     male         0.01
# 10 h     female       0.01
# 11 i     female       0.21
# 12 i     male         0.15
# 13 j     female       0.55
# 14 j     male         0.48
# 15 k     female       0.13
# 16 k     male         0.17
```

Comment: How would I create a mosaic plot with this data?

Comment: No idea. This is probably better to open a new question for that. Or check existing ones :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case `male` and `female` columns are not needed when reshaping. You can just select them out and then `pivot_longer()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(type, starts_with("prop")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-type, names_prefix = "prop_total_", names_to = "gender",
               values_to = "prop", values_drop_na = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 16 × 3
#    type  gender  prop
#    <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#  1 a     male    0.03
#  2 b     female  0.04
#  3 c     male    0.03
#  4 d     female  0.01
#  5 e     male    0.01
#  6 f     female  0.03
#  7 f     male    0.11
#  8 g     female  0.03
#  9 g     male    0.01
# 10 h     female  0.01
# 11 i     female  0.21
# 12 i     male    0.15
# 13 j     female  0.55
# 14 j     male    0.48
# 15 k     female  0.13
# 16 k     male    0.17
```

Comment: How would I create a mosaic plot with this data?

Comment: @CloftX It's completely a different issue. You should open a new post or search existing ones.